# Showing Before and After version of a dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

------Original Data----

**Before:**

```
    Speak English   Length  currentCode     currentName
0   True    1   $A  USA
1   True    2   $AM     Massachusetts
2   True    3   $AMB    Boston
3   True    3   $AMS    Springfield
4   True    3   $AMA    Amherst
5   True    3   $AMP    Plymouth
6   False   1   $D  Germany
7   False   2   $DB     Brandenburg
8   False   3   $DBB    Berlin
9   False   3   $DBD    Dresden
```

**After**

```
    Speak English   Length  futureCode  futureName
0   True    1   $A  America
1   True    2   $AM     Maine
2   True    3   $AMC    Brockton
3   True    3   $AMM    Main
4   False   1   $D  Denmark
5   False   2   $DC     Copenhagen
6   False   3   $DCC    Copper
7   False   3   $DCD    Dresden
```

**Goal:**

[image]
**Note:** The goal is in form of a pivot table in Excel. My codes:

```
import pandas as pd
before = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/BoBoMann/Desktop/Sequence.xlsx',sheet_name='Before')
after = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/BoBoMann/Desktop/Sequence.xlsx',sheet_name='After')
```

**Attempt #1:** Concatenate but do not know how to set index of Speak English and Length afterward:

```
pd.concat([before,after],axis = 1,keys=['Before','After'],join='outer')
```

**Attempt #2 :** Set index for each data frame but cannot concatenate along the columns as Pandas raises **ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!**

```
before = before.set_index(['Speak English','Length']).sort_index(axis = 0)
after = after.set_index(['Speak English','Length']).sort_index(axis = 0) 
pd.concat([before,after],axis = 1,keys=['Current','Future'],join='outer')
```

Thank you so much for your helps!

Comment: @anky_91: 'Speak English' is actually a single column. sorry for the bad data format. I tried your method, isn't it similar to my Attempt 2? as pandas still raises the same Value Error.

Comment: I see, yes it should since the combination of `Speak English` and `Length` has different entries and is not unique

Comment: can you try `pd.concat([i.set_index(['Speak English','Length'],append=True) for i in [before,after]]
          ,axis=1,keys=['before','after']).sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0)` ?

Comment: @anky_91: the code works but the format is still not similar to my goal :(

Comment: hi, did you manage to get a solution here?

Comment: @invertedOwlCoding: I think I did using win32com package